# validity of conditional proof

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

In many cases, many mathematical proofs tacitly use conditional proof(CP).

Including logic books, I've never seen why we can use CP. can somebody suggest some proof for validity of CP in general? or just recommendation books will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) is a proof where, having derived $B$ from *assumption* $A$, we conclude with :

> $A \to B$.

This proof is *valid* because form the definition of [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) we have that :

> if $\Gamma \cup \{ \alpha \} \vDash \beta$, then $\Gamma \vDash \alpha \to \beta$.

---

If for simplicity we consider *propositiona logic*, we have that :

> $\Gamma$ *logically implies* $\sigma$ (written : $\Gamma \vDash \sigma$) iff every truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\sigma$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\sigma$.

Thus, considering : $\Gamma \cup \{ \alpha \} \vDash \beta$, we have that every
truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma, \alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ and $\alpha$ also satisfies $\beta$.

Consider now a truth assignement $v$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$. We have two cases :

*(i)* if $v$ does not satisfy $\alpha$, then it satisies $\alpha \to \beta$ [see truth table for $\to$];

*(ii)* if instead $v$ satisfies $\alpha$, then by the assumption it satisfies also $\beta$, and so $v$ satisfies $\alpha \to \beta$.

In any case, $v$ satisfies $\alpha \to \beta$, and thus we have $\Gamma \vDash \alpha \to \beta$.

Comment: could you present me some books taking the conditional proof as inference rule? since I've only seen systems taking MP and many axioms(like enderton & hilbert style system), I might need some references later for this

Comment: @fbg - the "standard" system having CP as a primitve rule (among others) is *Natural Deduction*; see Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA17) (2007), page 17.

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks!